# zero AC gain of CMOS inverter

Tags: cmos, gain, spice, inverting-amplifier, ngspice

Why is the following AC analysis of CMOS inverter resulted in zero AC gain (vout/vin) ?

[image: CMOS inverter ac analysis]

Comment: Feedback resistor 1E20 ???

Comment: @LvW see the "alter" section

Comment: The phrase "alter section" may mean something to you but it does not mean anything to those of use who use other simulators. Try to be more clear with your statements. Also, using a screenshot as a graphic is asking for trouble...it's low quality. Try to export graphics from the software instead.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson alter is just to change the value of the parameter, in this case, switch to Rs2, open Rs1, turn on the Rf

Answer (score 1):

Removing Cout solves the zero AC gain issue.  Remember the RC constant = 100G * 1n = 100s, so 0.01Hz filtering on the AC gain plot result.

Answer (score 0):

Your source is DC coupled, with a very low source impedance, and it's pulling the input down out of the active region.

You need to put a capacitor in series with RS1, so that Rf can then bias the inverter back into the active region.

As others have said Rf is probably a bit big, normal values are 1E6 - 1E7.

Comment: see the "alter" section. The AC analysis is done without the Rf (by making it extremely large Ohm)

Answer (score 0):

The incremental gain is change in Vout over the change in Vin is and not just d3/d4.

The 1st plot appears to have a  peak gain ~ -3.34 at Vdd/2 for Vdd=1V

[image]

Comment: I am asking about "AC" gain

Comment: I am referring to the vout/vin plot in ac analysis

Comment: Fix your program Av=ΔVo/ΔVin

Comment: I am looking at ac1 result window (vout/vin), how do you get slope of 4.5 ?

Comment: bad eye, I meant 3.3

Comment: the DC sweep could be used for DC gain, check the ac1 result window with the plot title vout/vin.  We are discussing two different plots here. Remember, I am asking about AC gain plot

Comment: I cannot fix your SPice program, but your 1st plot shows   AC gain for low f by the slope of Av=ΔVo/ΔVin. SO you must save Vo(x),Vi(x) and compute the change for each increment

Comment: If you cannot, then Use 1M Rfeedback and AC couple 10mV input and measure output gain

Comment: In AC analysis, how would you come up with a gradient calculation ? tell me in AC , not in DC analysis

Comment: I dont use spice but I can easily compute in other programs